# Why am I getting this "tag not defined" error?

Tags: unity

In the log, it says

```
UnityException: Tag: car is not defined.
  at PlayerController.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm checking against the tag car when colliding, why does this happen? I have tagged the object, see picture below

heres some code

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("car"))//error here
    {
        //more code
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you didn't apply the changes. Anyways it was a different thing. Can you post some of your code and full inspector window snap?

Comment: @HamzaHasan yeah just changed the Q. Which part of the code do you want. I'll add some to the question

Comment: Seems everything fine. Try by restarting Unity. May be inspector settings got corrupt and may need restart.

Comment: I don't think your tags are there.

Comment: Its a bug. If you can reproduce it, please report it to Unity

Comment: @HamzaHasan I think because I copied project over to a different computer

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to handle Unity projects on other system without any source control. If you just copy and paste it anywhere else. You will get all tags empty. It is for sure

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that there weren't actually any tags in Edit > Project Settings > Tags and Layers, even though there were in the inspector